# Julia for image processing and speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, fibonacci, julia

I recently stumbled upon [Julia Language](http://julialang.org/) and I was surprised to see their claims. It claims to be many folds faster than languages like Python, which I'm currently using for machine learning algorithms on speech recogniton. 
Their claim for example Fibonacci sequence is about 30 times faster than in Python.

I dont understand what is that it makes it so much faster. However what I really want to know is whether someone has actually verified this. If that is the case I would move from Python to Julia Language for the speech recognizer I am building as I am hitting the slow threshold of my response and cannot afford to make it anymore slower. 
Also are there any projects on github(or anywhere) where I can find Julia projects which do heavy number crunching like image processing, speech recognition etc.
I searched upon some other link such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208014/is-the-julia-language-really-as-fast-as-it-claims)  , but could not decide effectively. I can run the programs and verify their claims, but if someone has already done so, it would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that surprising; Python made a number of decisions that make it a fairly slow language, and [Guido van Rossum, its creator, says](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/van-rossum-python-not-too-slow-188715) "It is usually much more effective to take that one piece and replace that one function or module with a little bit of code you wrote in C or C++ rather than rewriting your entire system in a faster language, because for most of what you're doing, the speed of the language is irrelevant." As a general rule, any language that is concerned with speed will be faster than Python: C, C++, Ada, Java, Scala, Clojure, a number of other languages, all show up more then an order of magnitude faster in typical implementations than Python in benchmarks. Unless the authors of Julia have completely failed in their attempts to make a faster language, it will be faster than Python.

Answer (score 4):

> I dont understand what is that it makes it so much faster.

People often assume Julia is fast due to some sort of superior JIT compiler and that Python could be optimized in the same way since they are both dynamic languages.

However it is actually all due to clever language design choices. All functions in Julia are multiple dispatch unlike Python functions. That means at runtime Julia can pick one particular code implementation for every possible combination of arguments. Since types are immutable in Julia the compiled machine code handling a particular case of argument combinations can be cached.

In Julia all libraries have also been designed with type stability in mind, meaning for a given set of argument types a function will always return objects of the same type. E.g. so if you do a mathematical operation on two integers and it returns and integers, then most of the time the JIT compiler will know that it ALWAYS returns an integer and thus don't have to create lots of code to check for every possible case.

If you are uncertain about the performance of Julia, I suggest you actually look at some small code examples and play with the code generator. With `@code_native`, you can see the assembly code Julia generates for a function. You will find it is possible to emit basically the same code as a C compiler would do. Quite dynamic and complex looking code in Julia surprisingly often just turns into a few assembly code instructions.

The thing with Julia is that you can't just look at the performance of some random library existing doing what you want. It could be a quick port or not well optimized. It is easy to write slow Julia code if you have no idea what you are doing. The key thing is that Julia gives you quite good tools for writing highly optimized code.

If you need to you can typically manage to get performance close to C. But of course you have to spend some time optimizing your code. Julia has functions which allows you to analyze your functions and tell you were you did something causing potential performance problems.

Fortunately Julia performance benefits from lots of small functions, so you can typically analyze performance issues in very small isolated cases.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding packages, there is a link to all registered "external packages" from the homepage. You may find some of the things you want there.